In a hypothetical race between a high-end bicycle from 2024, and a motorcycle from 1914, who would win?
In a hypothetical race between a high-end bicycle from 2024, and an average motorcycle from 1914, who would win and why?

The bicycle would be ridden by a world-class bicycle professional, riding a bicycle made using high-end technology in 2024.
The motorcycle would be ridden by an average person, using an average motorcycle from 1914 or before.

If they raced across modern Ottawa, who would win?

Looking at objective stats:

1914 Indian V-twin top speed: ~88.5kph
1914 Harley-Davidson Model 10A top speed ~80.5kph
1914 Harley-Davidson Model 10F top speed ~104.6kph
2024 Tour De France Stage 1 final 1km top speed: 70.6kph

Even if we assume that the bicycle rider doesn't get fatigued, the 1914 motorcycle wins. Maybe if modern Ottawa was all downhill (and that's a big maybe), the bicyclist would have a chance, but taking the law of averages, the motorcycle wins.

what about how matter of riding skill, if motorcycle ride by average joe but modern bicycle ride by world class bicycle user, also i think ancient motorcycle also lack abilty to maintain top speed for long time right?

Knowing "average joes" who ride bikes, they can traverse city streets. Considering the hypothetical situation is "modern Ottawa" and not a racetrack, I'm not concerned about their ability. Sustained speeds are still a matter of man vs. machine - both lack ability to maintain top speed for a long time.

Thank you for your edit! If I came off as rude, I apologize, but even small details like the year of motorbike can be important. Thanks! :)
